# find the highest number in loop

Tags: c#

I have a loop that repeats itself 100 times and every time it generates a number from 34.5 to 42.0

```
Random rnd = new Random();
const double MAX = 42.0;
const double MIN = 34.5;
//Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}",num);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  double num = rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
  Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}", num);
}
```

and I want to find the highest number and print it but I don't know how to find the number

Comment: `Double maxRandomDbl = Enumerable.Range( 0, 100 ).Select( _ => MIN + ( rng.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) ).Max();`

Comment: Statistically, given a large enough iteration count, the highest number will be `41.99999999999999999` btw. You might as well just return _that_ as a fixed value.

Comment: @Dai will it? What's the maximum double the random value will return? What will it become when the transformation is applied? Ieee754 is not the same as real arithmetic. There are things like rounding errors etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable outside the loop, and then set that to the minimum possible value. Then on each iteration, if the generated number is larger than that, store the generated number. Then after the loop you can print it out.

```cs
Random rnd = new Random();
const double MAX = 42.0;
const double MIN = 34.5;
double highestRandom = MIN;
//Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}",num);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    double num = rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
    if (num > highestRandom)
    {
        highestRandom = num;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}", num);
}

Console.WriteLine("The highest number was: {0:f1}", highestRandom);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FMXCL41290)

Answer (score 2):

You can store your values to a List and then find the max and min values

```
Random rnd = new Random();
const double MAX = 42.0;
const double MIN = 34.5;
//Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}",num);
List<double> lst = new List<double>(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{       
   double num = rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
   lst.Add(num);
   Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}", num);
}
Console.WriteLine("max number is " + lst.Max().ToString());
```

Comment: So you're proposing a loop to generate the numbers, and then a second loop to find the highest? How would the second loop work, and why can't the first one do it?

Comment: yeah that was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest change to your existing code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
const double MAX = 42.0;
const double MIN = 34.5;
//Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}",num);
double max = double.MinValue;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    double num = rnd.NextDouble() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
    max = num > max ? num : max;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0:f1}", max);
```